# Highly divisible numbers

Tags: number-theory

A positive integer $n$ is called *highly divisible* if $d(n) > d(m)$ for all positive integers $m < n$.

My book said that "All but finitely many highly divisible integers $a$ are divisible by $2$ and by $3^7$." I get how all but finitely many must be divisible by $2$ since we may write $n = 2^{\alpha_2(n)}3^{\alpha_3(n)} \cdots p^{\alpha_p(n)}$ and $\alpha_2(n) \geq \alpha_3(n) \geq \cdots \geq \alpha_p(n)$, but how do they get the $3^7$?

**Book:**

[image]

Comment: What book is it? Shortlisted IMO problems?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, you are right. It is 2005 IMO Shortlist N5.

Comment: But problem N5 asks about consecutive highly divisible numbers. Where did you get $2$ and $3^7$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde In the solution, which I will post now.

Comment: So you have the solution. :-) I planned to do it from scratch.

Comment: @S.Y It in is the solution from my book, which is where I got my question from. I am wondering how in the solution they can get that "All but finitely many highly divisible integers $a$ are divisible by $2$ and $3^7$."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the IMO shortlist N5 problem and will just solve the problem proposed by the OP.

1) For sufficiently large highly divisible $n$, we must have $\alpha_2(n) > 1000$. Otherwise, $1000 \ge  \alpha_2(n) \ge \alpha_3(n) \ge \cdots \ge \alpha_p(n)$, and we must have $p>2^{1001}$ since $n$ is sufficiently large. Let $m=2^{1001 + \alpha_2(n)}\cdot 3^{\alpha_3(n)}\cdots p^{\alpha_p(n)-1}$, we have $m<n$ and $d(m)\ge d(n)$, since $(1001+\alpha_2(n)+1) *\alpha_p(n) \ge 2*(\alpha_2(n)+1) *\alpha_p(n) \ge (\alpha_2(n)+1)(\alpha_p(n) + 1)$.

2) For these highly divisible $n$ with $\alpha_2(n) > 1000$, if $\alpha_3(n) < 7$, let $m=2^{\alpha_2(n)-14} 3^7\cdots p^{\alpha_p(n)}$. We have $m<n$ and  $d(m)\ge d(n)$  since $(\alpha_2(n)-14 + 1)*(7+1) \ge (\alpha_2(n) + 1)(6+1) \ge (\alpha_2(n) + 1)(\alpha_3(n)+1)$